# Probability of random sample of $50$ students from a class of $300$.

Tags: probability

> A simple random sample of $50$ students is taken from a class of $300$ students. In the class, the average midterm score is $67$ and the standard deviation(SD) is $12$, there are $72$ women. Let $W$ be the number of women in the sample, and let $S$ be the average midterm score of the sampled students.

$N=300;
n=50;
μ=E[S]=67;
σ=SD=12;
W=72;$

Find $E(W)$?=Expected value of Women?
E(W)=n*p=50*72/300=12

Find $SE(W)$?=Standard error of Women?

and Find $E(S)$?= Expected value of student tast score? $E(S) =μ=E[S]=67 $

Find $SE(S)$?=Standard Error of Student midterm test Score?

$SE(S)={[σ/sqrt(n)]*[$\sqrt((N-n)/(N-1))]}$

$SE(S)={[12/sqrt(50)]*[(300-50)/(300-1)]}=1.55178$

Answer (score 0):

Note that here $W \sim Binomial(n=50,p=\dfrac{72}{300})$

So $E(W)=np=50 \cdot \dfrac{72}{300}$ and $SE(W)=\sqrt{np(1-p)}=\sqrt{50 \cdot \dfrac{72}{300}\left(1-\dfrac{72}{300}\right)}$.

Again $E(S)=\bar x =67$ and $SE(S)=\sqrt{\dfrac{\sigma ^2}{n}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{12^2}{50}}$